# Converting DWG surface to line feature class in file geodatabase using FME?

Tags: file-geodatabase, fme-form, dwg, surface

I have a DWG file with autocad_surfaces.

I want to export these to a line, so that I can use it in ArcGIS Pro.

How can I convert the features from surfaces to lines in an ArcGIS File Geodatabase using FME 2018?

Answer (score 1):

Well the key issue there is that a surface is a continuous area of measurements, whereas a line is a series of discrete points. So there has to be a decision on how you want to extract points from that surface, and how you want them to be joined together.

I suspect the transformer to use is the SurfaceModeller. Point the surface feature(s) into the Points/Lines input port. Then take the output from maybe the Contours output port, or the VertexPoints (and then join them together with a LineBuilder transformer).

Those methods would give you irregular lines. The other solution is to take the DEMRaster output and use a RasterCellCoercer to turn that into points. Then you have a regular DEM grid, which again you could use the LineBuilder to join up.

However, I would question why you need to turn this into lines, just to get this into a different format. As far as I know, File Geodatabase does support surface-type geometries. So there shouldn't be a need to convert the geometry type so radically, just to get the data in there (of course, if you need the data in a different geometry to carry out a different action on it, that's fine).

Comment: Thank you. I will try this out. I want it to become the centerline of the surface so that I can represent it in a GIS-database which stores pipe centerlines.

Comment: There's a CentreLineReplacer transformer, but you'll need to get the data from a surface into a polygon before you could use that. I don't think it would work on a surface.